# How to change names of scraped images with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

So I need to download the images of every coin on the list on CoinGecko, so I wrote the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 
    
htmldata = getdata("https://www.coingecko.com/en") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
for item1 in soup.select('.coin-icon img'):
    link = item1.get('data-src').replace('thumb', 'thumb_2x')
    with open(basename(link), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

However, I need to save the images with their names being the same as the ticker of the coin of that list from CoinGecko (rename `bitcoin.png?1547033579` to `BTC.png`, `ethereum.png?1595348880` to `ETH.png`, and so forth). There are over 7000 images that need to be renamed, and many of them have quite unique names, so slicing does not work here.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: so you're asking how to rename `bitcoin.png?1547033579` to `Bitcoin.png`? `basename(link).split('?')[0].upper()`

Comment: I edited OP so it makes better sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was browsing the html file and I found that the  tag you are looking at has an alt parameter that has the ticker on the end of the string.

```
<div class="coin-icon mr-2 center flex-column">
<img class="" alt="bitcoin (BTC)" data-src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579" data-srcset="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb_2x/bitcoin.png?1547033579 2x" src="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579" srcset="https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb_2x/bitcoin.png?1547033579 2x">
</div>
```

So we can use that to get the correct name like so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 
    
htmldata = getdata("https://www.coingecko.com/en") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
for item1 in soup.select('.coin-icon img'):
    link = item1.get('data-src').replace('thumb', 'thumb_2x')
    raw_name = item1.get('alt')
    name = raw_name[raw_name.find('(') + 1:-1]
    with open(basename(name), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

We are basically extracting the value between the parenthesis using string slicing.

Comment: That's it, nice! It is the first time I come accross such command "+ 1:-1" could you point me where I can read more on what it is and the logic behind it?

Comment: It is python string slicing, a very powerful tool specially for web scrapping. 
What I am doing is just kind of a clever way to use the indexing on the string slicing. You can slice the string by index positively and negatively and I am combining both.
For the string example = 'america': |
example[1] => 'm' |
example[-2] => 'c' |
example[-4:] => 'rica' |

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Take a closer look at the code, the bit that slices the string is "raw_name[raw_name.find('(') + 1:-1]" and not just  "+ 1:-1"!

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could do alternatively:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en"

r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for item1 in soup.select('td.coin-name[data-text]'):
    ticker_name = item1.select_one(".center > span").get_text(strip=True)
    image_link = item1.select_one(".coin-icon > img").get('data-src').replace('thumb','thumb_2x')
##    with open(f"{basename(ticker_name)}.png", "wb") as f:
    with open(basename(ticker_name), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(image_link).content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could achieve this very easily using string slicing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path  import basename

def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 
    
htmldata = getdata("https://www.coingecko.com/en") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
for item1 in soup.select('.coin-icon img'):
    link = item1.get('data-src').replace('thumb', 'thumb_2x')
    with open(basename(link[:link.find('?')]), "wb") as f:
            f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```

I am slicing a section of the link string using [:] and looking for the question mark that marks the beginning of the query.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I need to happen, I edited original post so it makes more sense now. I need to rename the images to their respective tickers of the same list that I scrape them from (```bitcoin.png?1547033579``` to ```BTC.png```, ```ethereum.png?1595348880``` to ```ETH.png``` and so forth)